# Uncertainty principle using fourier transforms

Tags: wavefunction, fourier-transform, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle

I am trying to show the uncertainty relation of $\Delta x\Delta p = \frac{\hbar}{2}$ using a gaussian wave function and its Fourier transform. I have found correctly the uncertainty in position $\Delta x = \frac{\sigma}{\sqrt 2}$ and am trying to find the uncertainty of the wavenumber to get the uncertainty in momentum. I am getting the reciprocal of what it is supposed to be, can someone tell me what I am doing wrong? Here is my working for the uncertainty in the wave number, I am getting $\Delta k= \sqrt 2 \sigma$ but it should be $\Delta k = \frac{1}{\sqrt 2 \sigma}$ : [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the expression
$$
e^{-k^2 \sigma^2}
$$
to find the standard deviation you can compare it to the function
$$
e^{-x^2/2 a^2}.
$$
In this function of $x$, the standard deviation is $a$.
So the general statement about Gaussian functions is that they have the form
$$
\exp( - x^2 / 2 \Delta x^2 )
$$
or in the case you are interested in,
$$
e^{ - k^2 / 2 \Delta k^2 }.
$$
Equating this to $e^{- k^2 \sigma^2}$ you get
$$
 \frac{1}{2 \Delta k^2} = \sigma^2 
$$
So we have
$$
\Delta k = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2} \sigma}.
$$
Combining this with $\Delta x = \sigma / \sqrt{2}$ gives
$$
\Delta x \Delta k = \frac{1}{2}
$$

Comment: So I compare the squared $\widetilde{ \psi }(k)$ to the standard gaussian in order to get the uncertainty in k?

Comment: Yes, because the standard deviation is an aspect of the probability distribution.

Answer (score 0):

When solving for $\Delta k$ you write $$\frac{(\Delta k)^{2}}{2}=\sigma^{2}$$ Where did this statement come from? Maybe start with $$\frac{(\Delta k)^{2}\sigma^2}{2}=1$$